# Al intentar correr una query en Laravel, arroja un error 500 y consulta vacía [], en cambio en Postgres funciona sin errores

Tags: postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

Tengo problemas al realizar una consulta con join, comparando varias columnas en ambas tablas, para extraer un solo dato completo con todas las columnas.

```php
$nomina = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('nomina')
        ->join('unidad','nomina.anocur','=','unidad.anocur')
        ->where('nomina.codper','=','00123456')
        ->where('unidad.oficina','=','nomina.oficina')
        ->where('unidad.lugar','=','nomina.lugar')
        ->where('unidad.deparamento','=','nomina.deparamento')
        ->where('unidad.sub_departamento','=','nomina.sub_departamento')
        ->where('unidad.codigo_nomina','=','nomina.codigo_nomina')
        ->where('unidad.organizacion','=','nomina.organizacion')
        ->select('*')->get()->first();
```

Al intentar correr el Query en laravel, arroja un error 500 y consulta vacía []... En cambio con la misma consulta estructurada en Postgres, funciona sin errores, extrayendo todas las columnas, con el siguiente Query

```sql
select * from nomina 
inner join unidad 
on nomina.anocur = unidad.anocur 
where nomina.codper = '00123456'
and unidad.oficina = nomina.oficina 
and unidad.lugar = nomina.lugar
and unidad.deparamento = nomina.deparamento 
and unidad.sub_departamento = nomina.sub_departamento
and unidad.codigo_nomina = nomina.codigo_nomina
and unidad.organizacion = nomina.organizacion
```

¿De qué otra manera se puede realizar, para obtener los resultados de Postgres en Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la manera como tienes planteado, el query builder por debajo manda la sentencia

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    nomina
    INNER JOIN unidad ON nomina.anocur = unidad.anocur
WHERE
    nomina.codper = '00123456'
    AND unidad.oficina = 'nomina.oficina'
    AND unidad.lugar = 'nomina.lugar'
    AND unidad.deparamento = 'nomina.deparamento'
    AND unidad.sub_departamento = 'nomina.sub_departamento'
    AND unidad.codigo_nomina = 'nomina.codigo_nomina'
    AND unidad.organizacion = 'nomina.organizacion'
```

O sea, intenta hacer el where contra cadenas de texto y no contra campos de `nomina`.

Ignoro por qué te sale un error 500, Aunque está fuera del alcance de esta pregunta, debieras revisar en `storage/logs` para saber más.

Para lo que nos convoca: lo que quieres hacer (aunque no es la única manera) podría implementarse usando un join con una función como segundo parámetro.

```
$nomina = DB::connection('pgsql')->table('nomina')
    ->join('unidad',function($join) {
        $join->on('nomina.anocur','=','unidad.anocur')
             ->on('unidad.oficina','=','nomina.oficina')
             ->on('unidad.lugar','=','nomina.lugar')
             ->on('unidad.deparamento','=','nomina.deparamento')
             ->on('unidad.sub_departamento','=','nomina.sub_departamento')
             ->on('unidad.codigo_nomina','=','nomina.codigo_nomina')
             ->on('unidad.organizacion','=','nomina.organizacion');
    })
    ->where('nomina.codper','=','00123456')
    ->select('*')->get()->first();
```

Fíjate que el `where` contra el escalar '00123456' se mantiene tal cual, y no debe meterse dentro del join.